# Javascript IE findindex error

Tags: javascript, liquid

I have the following code works great in almost all browsers... except Firefox and IE...

```
handles.forEach(function (handle) {
let clIndex = collections.findIndex(function (col) {
  return col.handle == handle;
});

if (clIndex != -1) {
  sorted.push(collections[clIndex]);
};

requests--;
```

});

The error is:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'findIndex'

I have found this but don't see the way to implement it: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: Just use the polyfill. Copy & paste (at the top of your js file) the code you found on linked page and it'll work

Comment: Are you sure `collections` is an Array? The error tells you it's trying to find `findIndex` on `Object`, but it only exists on `Array`.

Comment: Yes `var collections = [];` is called above and filled with the response. `if (requests == 0) { collections.push( { title: "{{collection.title}}", products: products, handle: "{{ collection.handle }}" } );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to use `.findIndex()` on an Object that isn't of type Array then this function won't work. That is to say, `collections` must be an Array. Check to see if this is true.

Comment: Yes   var collections = []; is called above and filled with the response.     if (requests == 0) {
   collections.push( {
    title: "{{collection.title}}",
    products: products,
    handle: "{{ collection.handle }}"
  } );